# Styling md-input-element

Tags: html, css, angular, styling, angular-material2

I am trying to style the `.md-input-element` on `md-input` which is added by default from `angular-material.css` which seems I cannot get to work. I cam trying to add the letter-spacing style but it only works as the current. style on the console. Is there any way to override this particular style for `md-input-element` in my own css file?

My html code is as below :

```
<!-- Input Name* -->
                <div class="mdl-grid">
                    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-cell--8-col-tablet mdl-cell--4-col-phone">
                        <div class="name-padding">
                            <md-input class="mdl-textfield--full-width" mandatory type="text" id="name" formControlName="name" placeholder="Name"
                                [(ngModel)]="outlet.name">
                                <md-hint *ngIf="formErrors.name">{{ formErrors.name }}</md-hint>
                            </md-input>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

css :

```
.md-input-element {
    letter-spacing: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: try using !important in your css.. `.md-input-element{letter-spacing:0 !important; }`

Comment: do  you add some code ?

Comment: It still would not get affected

Comment: I added `.md-input-element {
    letter-spacing: 1px
}` in styles.css of my angular2 component and it works. Would this be accurate in terms of styling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the style in the component that contains the mentioned html code, then it will not work because of the standard `ViewEncapsulation`. The default ist `Emulated` and will change your CSS-selector to something like the following during runtime:

```
.md-input-element[_ngcontent-xsa-40] {
{
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

This selector will not match with `class="md-input-element"` of the `md-input` because of the attached attribute.

**Now you have three options**

1. **Use /deep/**: You can rewrite your selector using deep. E.g. `:host /deep/ .md-input-element` to stop Angular2 adding the cryptic attribute to your selector.
2. **Change ViewEncapsulation**: You can change your ViewEncapsulation to `None` to stop Angular2 adding the cryptic attribute to your selector.
3. **Global style**: Add the style to a global `style.css` to get around the ViewEncapsulation

Look here for more information about styling your components https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html

Comment: I am using it in the styles.css at the moment. For which I need to take a look at the angular docs once more. Thanks for this :)

Answer (score 0):

try with below selector

```
md-input-container:not(.md-input-invalid).md-input-focused .md-input {
    letter-spacing:0!important;
    border-color: orange;
}
```

Comment: It still does not work. I am using angular-material2 alpha9.3 and md-input-container is not included in that version isnt it?